# Entity Framework Power Tools oracle code first

Tags: entity-framework, oracle11g

Testing Entity Framework Reverse Engineer Code First for Oracle.
The process ends correctly, but no classes for the data model are created.
Just context.cs is created.
I don't know if the reason for that can be the beta version, or something is wrong on my side.

Using:
• VStudio 2012
• Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4.
• ODAC 11.2 Release 5
• Oracle Developer Tools for VS (11.2)

Comment: By default Power Tools work with MS SQL. But have you read http://blog.devart.com/using-entity-framework-power-tools-ctp1-with-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html? It's older, but still has point.